# bash script command line parameters beginning with hyphen are ignored

Tags: linux, bash

I've written a VERY simple bash script to sync files, but I can't get the script to read the parameters correctly when the parameters are: -e "ssh -p 1234".  I realized I need to escape the quotes to get those to display properly, so: -e \"ssh -p 1234\", but the -e is ignored.  I tried quoting it, which gets it to show up if I echo out $option, but it still doesn't work properly.  Any advice to what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash
host=`hostname -s`
if [ "$host" = "machine1" ]; then
        transfer_to="machine2";
else
        transfer_to="machine1";
fi

# use $option when passing in. i.e --delete, -e "ssh -p 1234"
option="$@"
rsync -va $option /var/sync_dir/ $transfer_to:/var/sync_dir --progress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either use `$@` directly or copy it to an array:

```
rsync -va "$@" /var/sync_dir/ $transfer_to:/var/sync_dir --progress
```

or

```
option=("$@")
rsync -va "${option[@]}" /var/sync_dir/ $transfer_to:/var/sync_dir --progress
```